# How to sort custom columns for custom post type without meta query and pre_get_posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, pre-get-posts

I have a custom post type `orders` and multiple custom columns. I've added the custom columns with the `manage_orders_posts_columns` hook and registered the columns as sortable with this hook: `manage_edit-orders_sortable_columns`.

My issue is that some of the column values are not simply meta fields; the info displayed in these columns is generated based on multiple conditions related to custom functionality.

So my question is: is there any way to make a custom column sortable other than using the `pre_get_posts` hook and modifying the query?